# Javascript Regex to add <br> after every n number of words - No CSS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex but I seem to be getting nowhere with it.

I have a sentence as follow:

```
"Hey, diddle, diddle, The cat and the fiddle, The cow jumped over the moon; The little dog laughed To see such sport, And the dish ran away with the spoon."
```

I want to add a `<br/>` every `n` number of words. For example if I did it every `3` words it would look like this...

```
"Hey, diddle, diddle,<br/>
The cat and<br/>
the fiddle, The<br/>
etc..."
```

I know about word wrap css and I purely am looking for a javascript solution to this. I'm not sure if it is possible with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a regex that selects 3 words, and then replace it with a `<br>` appended.

```js
function wordWrap(string, numWordsPerLine) {
  return string.replace(
    RegExp('(?:\\S+\\s*){' + numWordsPerLine + '}', 'g'),
    '$&<br>'
  );
}

var input = "Hey, diddle, diddle, The cat and the fiddle, The cow jumped over the moon; The little dog laughed To see such sport, And the dish ran away with the spoon.";
document.body.innerHTML = wordWrap(input, 3);
```

Comment: why the extra `\` before the S ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik The extra backslash is needed because I'm using a string literal instead of a regex literal, so I have to escape backslashes.